# Bing maps used offline: cache tiles from its web service

Tags: windows-mobile, bing-maps

I'm developing a Windows Mobile application that uses Bing Maps Web Service to show user's position on it.

I think I have a problem if the user hasn't got internet service on his mobile, so I think I can cache the tiles of a city, for example, so the user doesn't need to be online to use my application.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bing Maps does support tiling at all.  What you would have to do it save each of the images that you download from the service locally, along with the metadata about it (location, radius, etc) and then write your own algorithm for how to load those images based on location data.

Not impossible, but a fair bit of work.